# getting error: download file to specific location, C#, winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, file, download

I am preparing a windows forms application and i want to download a file to desktop and copy that to data grid.
i wrote some code but i am not bale to get the results... can some one rectify and show me the solution....
the code as follows....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



namespace market_lot_info
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection Econ;

        string constr, Query;
        string conStr = string.Empty;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\OIAtool");
            if (dir.Exists)
                dir.Delete(true);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\OIAtool");

            WebClient wc=new WebClient();


            // download file to specified folder

            string filepath = @"C:\OIAtool\" + "fo_mktlots.csv";
            string urlmktlot = @"http://www.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_mktlots.csv";
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.nseindia.com");
            string filename = string.Empty;


            uri = new Uri(urlmktlot);
            filename = @"C:\OIAtool\" + "fo_mktlots.csv";

            constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", filepath);
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
            wc.DownloadFile(uri, filename);


            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + filename + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");
            Econ = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

            Econ.Open();

            Query = string.Format("Select * FROM " + "[" + filename + "$]");


            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Query, conn);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            Econ.Close();
            //oda.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            dataGridViewLotInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


        }

    }
}
```

On the `Econ.Open();` I am getting the following error:

> The ConnectionString has not be properly initialized.

[image]

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?! what happens when you run the code? You got to be more clear about your question

Comment: You need to edit your question with the error you get and try not to add it as a picture.

Comment: Hi @VenkattSwameSoma if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Please open a new question if you have a new problem. Do not just change the question to reflect a new problem or this question will be voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

You never give a value to `conStr` but you define `constr`

```
// capital 'S'
string conStr = string.Empty;

// lower case 's'
constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", filepath);
```

I am guessing this is unintentional.
You will want to change it to:

```
// capital 'S'
conStr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", filepath);
```

Comment: thank you sir, i changed both to same format... now i am getting following error.....       " External table is not in the expected format. "

Comment: I do not know the format of your table. If you have a new problem please open a new question with the details for that problem. SO is not a code writing service.